# Karate Mock Server handler is synchronized

Tags: karate

I am running karate standalone jar to serve mocks. When the incoming request does not match any scenario, we are proxying to actual server with karate.proceed().  In this case, karate server slows down. How can i improve the performance of karate server?

Comment: keep in mind karate is for "mocks" not production :) that said, we've never got this feedback. if you can simulate the problem in a simple sample, please follow this process, and we will investigate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue